# How can I use pip to install modules in a specific directory without root access?

Tags: python

I'm on a Linux machine running Red Hat.  I installed Python 2.7.12 in a location in my home directory: `~/PYTHON`.  I also installed setuptools and pip in the same location.  Now, I would like to use pip to install modules in that same location.  However, if I try something like this:

```
pip install matplotlib --prefix=/home/myuserid/PYTHON
```

It fails with a permission error on this file: `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyparsing-1.5.6-py2.7.egg-info`.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I tell pip to install modules in `~/PYTHON`?  Also, how should I set the python environment variables?

Comment: Run `type -P pip`. Is it in the user install of Python under `~/PYTHON`? Or is it in a global path? Something tells me it's the latter, and you never added `$HOME/PYTHON/bin` to your `PATH`.

Comment: Try `--target <dir>`. Alternatively, use `--user` to install into `~/.local`

Comment: `pip` probably references the copy for the system python installation. you need to call the copy of pip you installed in your user folder. This will require the full path to the specific one, or an alias. something like `./~PYTHON/scripts/pip -otherargs...`

Comment: If I do a 'which pip, it references the pip in ~/PYTHON: which pip
/home/myuserid/PYTHON/bin/pip

Comment: The "--target ,dir" seemed to work.  Thanks!